# Call Back Function issue

Tags: c++, function, callback

I am experimenting with call-back functions and I can't see what is going wrong here.

func1 takes two function pointers to which I pass pointers to func2 and func3. func2 should wait 5 seconds before printing to cout and func3 should wait 12 seconds before printing to cout. The wait() function I have implemented myself but not included here.

When the program runs, after 5 seconds, both func2 and func3 print out at the same time. I would have expected to wait 5 seconds for func2 to print and then another 12 seconds later for func3 but this is not the case.

Can anyone see what is wrong here if anything? Many thanks in advance.

```
#define ONE_SEC 1000000000/3

void wait(int);
void func1(void(*)(), void(*)());
void func2();
void func3();

int main()
{

    std::cout<<"In Main Program!!"<<std::endl;

    void (*funcPtr2)();
    void (*funcPtr3)();

    funcPtr2 = func2;
    funcPtr3 = func3;


    func1(funcPtr2, funcPtr3);

    return 0;
}

void func1(void (*fptr2)(), void (*fptr3)())
{
    std::cout<<"In function one!!"<<std::endl;
    (*fptr2)();
    (*fptr3)();
}

void func2()
{
     wait(5);
     std::cout<<"In function 2 - callback function!!"<<std::endl;

}

void func3()
{
    wait(20);
    std::cout<<"In function 3 - callback function!!"<<std::endl;
}

void wait (int secs)
{
    long j;
    long i;

    for (i = 0; i < secs * (ONE_SEC); i++)
    {
        j++;
    }

}
```

Comment: *"The wait() function I have implemented myself but not included here. "* We may have found the problem, then.

Comment: There is an issue with how long your program is waiting to execute certain functions, but you don't show the code responsible for *doing* the waiting.  Do you see the problem with that?

Comment: I have included the wait() code now

Answer (score 1):

Since your reinvention of the wheel doesn't work, try this out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "yo" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    std::cout << "whats" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    std::cout << "up" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

If you can't and you are on windows, go for Sleep(seconds) else usleep on unix

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
 void wait ( int seconds )
 {
    clock_t endwait;
    endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
    while (clock() < endwait) {}
 }

 void func1(void(*)(), void(*)());
 void func2();
 void func3();

 int main()
 {

    std::cout<<"In Main Program!!"<<std::endl;

    void (*funcPtr2)();
    void (*funcPtr3)();

    funcPtr2 = func2;
    funcPtr3 = func3;


    func1(funcPtr2, funcPtr3);

    return 0;
 }

 void func1(void (*fptr2)(), void (*fptr3)())
 {
    std::cout<<"In function one!!"<<std::endl;
    (*fptr2)();
    (*fptr3)();
 }

 void func2()
 {
    wait(5);
    std::cout<<"In function 2 - callback function!!"<<std::endl;

 }

 void func3()
 {
    wait(20);
    std::cout<<"In function 3 - callback function!!"<<std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you HAVE to be implementing your own `wait` function, and not calling one of the more reasonable `this_thread::sleep_for` or checks against `clock()` implementations, then the code below (your code) has undefined behavior because you never initialize `j`:

```
void wait (int secs)
{
    long j;
    long i;

    for (i = 0; i < secs * (ONE_SEC); i++)
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Primitive types (`int`, `long`, `bool`, `char`) need to be default initialized because there is no constructor for them (they're not actual classes in C++). (When the variable exists at file/namespace scope, it will be zero-initialized, but that's rarely the case). So simply setting `j` to `0` will get rid of your undefined behavior:

```
void wait (int secs)
{
    long j = 0;
    long i;

    for (i = 0; i < secs * (ONE_SEC); i++)
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```

But it's kind of redundant isn't it? Won't the following be the same?

```
void wait (int secs)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < secs * (ONE_SEC); i++)
    {}
}
```

However, the issue with this is that, unless `ONE_SEC` and `secs` are determined at compile-time or run-time depending on your system, you're almost never guaranteed that your program will wait the specified amount of time. As your hardware improves, you'll wait less and less time.

Ultimately, I'd say to go with the now-standard `this_thread::sleep_for()` like [another user posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31540638/27678):

```
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>
// ...
void wait (int secs)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(secs));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used the windows function Sleep() instead and the behavior is as expected. I still don't understand why my function won't work tho. I would expect ONE_SEC and sec should be the correct values throughout the program..

Comment: The problem is that your compiler is going to optimize that loop. Unroll it, maybe even remove it entirely because it's empty. You can't depend on a counting for loop to ever consume a certain amount of time